# How to handle the null value while fetching from DataStore?

Tags: java, exception, jdo

I have a property contactKey in GAE Datastore. Initially the value of the contactKey will be null. Then I will store the value for the contactKey which will be the key of the different JDO.

The problem is the following method will be called so many times in different places. So, the same data will be written many times.  When I tried to check the equality it throwed null pointer exception, since initially the contactKey is null. I want to persist without caring about the null or valid value. Is that possible?

```
public void saveContactLogJDO(ContactLogJDO contactLog, Long key)
{
    try {
        ContactJDO contactJdo = null;
        persist(contactLog);
        //This returns entire entity
        contactJdo = utils.getById(contactJdo.class,key);
        contactJdo.setContactByKey(contactLog.getId());
        utils.persist(contactJdo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        utils.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

I want to do the following check but getContactByKey throws null pointer exception since initially the value is null

```
if(contactLog.getId()!=null && contactLog != null){
    if(!contactJdo.getContactByKey().equals(contactLog.getId())){
            contactJdo.setContactByKey(contactLog.getId());
            utils.persist(contactJdo);
        }
}
```

Comment: Not really following what you are trying to do, if you can please explain a bit more. 
But from code only, maybe you can try converting the if like: if(contactLog !=null && contactLog.getId()!=null)

Comment: I don't want to persist if the contactKey equals contactLog.getId(). If I add the condition like
   if(!(contactJdo.getContactByKey().equals(contactLog.getId()))
It throws null pointer exception since I have the value of the contactKey in contactJdo as null

Comment: I want to persist the key though the JDO contains the contactKey value as valid or null.

Comment: So if you switch them does it works as you want?
if(!contactJdo.getContactByKey().equals(contactLog.getId())){ ==>
if(!contactLog.getId().equals(contactJdo.getContactByKey())){

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it still throws null pointer exception.